# Use same GPS location code on multiple fragments

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, location

I want to make an application that will include five different fragments. In each fragment I need the GPS location of the device but the purpose will be different.

In order not to implement FusedLocationProviderClient five times for each fragment, I was thinking of doing this once in MainActivity and sending the results to the  displayed fragment.

Being a beginner in java programming I ask you for guidance. How can I determine the GPS location of the device and the location is automatically sent (at each update) to the active fragment?

Maybe something like a service? Any sample code will be welcome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a place for specific programming questions (you did not post any code). StackOverflow is not a service for writing programs for free. Please attempt your project, and if you run into any specific issues come back with the code and ask a question then (after doing some research).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple solution to this using `ViewModel`.

The concept is that you initialize a state holder and share the same instance of that holder across your fragments.

The instance of that holder is stored in your activity.

Your ViewModel might look like this

```java
public class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private MutableLiveData<LatLng> location = new MutableLiveData<LatLng>();
    public LiveData<LatLng> getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    private void setLocation(LatLng value) {
        location.setValue(value)
    }
}
```

In your activity get the instance of this viewModel. We use the ViewModelProvider factory for this.

```
private MyViewModel model;

//in your activity onCreate
model = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel.class);

//and from location callback
model.setLocation(latlng)
```

In all of your fragments you can observe this data

```java
//first get the same instance of your ViewModel onViewCreated
model = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
model.getLocation().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), item -> {
    // Update the UI.
    //will execture everytime new data is set
});
```

Include required dependency in your app `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    def lifecycle_version = "2.0.0"

    implementation  "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"

    // alternately - if using Java8, use the following instead of lifecycle-compiler
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycle_version"
}
```

Learn more about `ViewModel` [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel?gclid=CjwKCAjwrNmWBhA4EiwAHbjEQE3hGwOQsAI1R9G5m__bJsuzqqJSKfW2m-jq3eS-iudqcIL695XBXBoCGAsQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds#java)